# How to assign a function to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I need to access an array element using its function.

For example, I have Array A[], now I want to create array B, such that

```
A[i] === B[i].value()
```

I tried below code but I am getting error as `B[i].value is not a function`

```
<script>
function test(A) {
    var B = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        B[i] = function value() {
                return A[i];
            };
    }

    for(var i=0; i< B.length; i++) {
        console.log(B[i].value());
    }
    return B;
}

A=[1,2,3];
B = test(A);
</script>
```

What is the correct way for this?

Comment: `A[i] === B[i].value()` - there is smth wrong

Comment: The (optional) name of a function expression is only available within the function, it doesn't create a named property of the object it's assigned to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign an object instead:

```
B[i] = {
    value: function () {
        return A[i];
    }
}
```

To avoid any problems with the scope of `i`, you can use the statement **[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)**

> The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

```js
function test(A) {
  var B = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    B[i] = {
      value: function() {
        return A[i];
      }
    };
  }

  for (let k = 0; k < B.length; k++) {
    console.log(B[k].value());
  }
  return B;
}

var B = test([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(B)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Ele, Is there any other way to add this function?

Comment: *closures* people! Change the second counter to `j`. Six votes - amusing!

Comment: Yes, If I use` j` in my second loop instead of `i`, it did not work, got error

Comment: @Igor six votes because the OP wants to call the function as follow `B[index].value()`.  Of course, you're right about the scope problem.  See the updated answer!

Comment: @Ele OP also wants `B[i].value === B[j].value`. OP does not know what they want.

Comment: @Igor yes, but the main problem was `B[i].value is not a function`.  Anyway, thank you for letting me know about the scope problem.

Comment: @user3181365 if you want to call the function as follow `B[index].value()` this is the most suitable way.

Comment: Be wary of IE and Edge, some versions support `let` but don't use proper lexical scoping so `for(let...` will have the same issues as `for(var...)` in those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could make value anonymous e.g. `B[i] = function () { /* Your code */ }` then just call `B[i]()` instead of `B[i].value()`